# Bottom white bar of Android Q gestures

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm trying to get the background to fullscreen basically, but I'm not sure what's wrong the navigation bar at the bottom is white

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: double.infinity,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code I even tried the setEnabledSystemUIOverlays but that's not working. I've tried googling for the answer but it seems to work fine for others?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the following way -

- Disable the bottom overlay (you have done that already but at wrong place)
- Remove extra padding from bottom.

**Disable the bottom overlay**

As you have already use `SystemChrome` service to disable the bottom overlay, but we should always disable the overlay before the application is run for this you can modify `main` method like this -

```
void main() {

  //Makes sure that flutter engine and widget bindings are initialized!
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();  

  //Only enables the overlays specified in the list 
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);

  //Run the App Widget
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

After you modify your app your app will look something like this  -

[image]

As you can see there is still some padding at the bottom (white bar), you can get rid of this white padding by using `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` property of the scaffold, and the padding at the bottom will be removed, your scaffold code will look something like this -

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: double.infinity,
      ),
    );
  }
```

And finally your app will look something like this -

[image]

Hope this helps!